# Sending data to server using TCP from two different client machines

Tags: python, c, sockets, tcp, client-server

I set up a Client/Server on two machines running same HW/SW/OS. Communication is done using TCP.
The server receives the incoming traffic and parse it successfully. I can see it in my logs (DB).
Message was sent using C code.

Now I've tried to send the same data from a different machine that has different HW/SW/OS. The Server received the incoming packets but it's failed to parse them (my SW failed to parse them), I can't see it in my logs.
Message was sent using simple python code:

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '10.1.10.121'
TCP_PORT = 8888
MESSAGE1 = '004a0d09fedcba04100f672d0904badcfe08f072f0720d0200e1b40000000044e90e0c520600cb2067e311016e719e0300000000eb2a6bbb9257d61374634ec0000000000000090d'.decode('hex')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
#s.send(MESSAGE1)
s.sendto(MESSAGE1, ('10.1.10.121',8888))
s.close()
```

I captured the two packets, one sent by different but same type of machine, and the second by completely different machine.

**Sent by same type of machine, client:**

```
10:30:15.041752 IP 10.1.10.114.60960 > 10.1.10.121.8888: Flags [P.], seq 72:144, ack 1, win 1002, options [nop,nop,TS val 2335115935 ecr 3243788988], length 72
        0x0000:  4500 007c bb72 4000 4006 561d 0a01 0a72  E..|.r@.@.V....r
        0x0010:  0a01 0a79 ee20 22b8 4756 ac42 f082 5712  ...y..".GV.B..W.
        0x0020:  8018 03ea 295b 0000 0101 080a 8b2f 0a9f  ....)[......./..
        0x0030:  c158 4abc 004a 0d09 fedc ba04 100f 672d  .XJ..J........g-
        0x0040:  0904 badc fe08 f072 f072 0d02 00e1 b400  .......r.r......
        0x0050:  0000 0044 e90e 0c52 0600 cb20 67e3 1101  ...D...R....g...
        0x0060:  6e71 9e03 0000 0000 eb2a 6bbb 9257 d613  nq.......*k..W..
        0x0070:  7463 4ec0 0000 0000 0000 090d            tcN.........
```

**Sent by different type of machine:**

```
04:59:50.496408 IP 10.1.1.26.50282 > 10.1.10.121.8888: Flags [P.], seq 1:73, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 517330441 ecr 1079241846], length 72
        0x0000:  4500 007c d474 4000 4006 4673 0a01 011a  E..|.t@.@.Fs....
        0x0010:  0a01 0a79 c46a 22b8 9f09 027c 8b0d 3d1a  ...y.j"....|..=.
        0x0020:  8018 00e5 69b4 0000 0101 080a 1ed5 d609  ....i...........
        0x0030:  4053 ec76 004a 0d09 fedc ba04 100f 672d  @S.v.J........g-
        0x0040:  0904 badc fe08 f072 f072 0d02 00e1 b400  .......r.r......
        0x0050:  0000 0044 e90e 0c52 0600 cb20 67e3 1101  ...D...R....g...
        0x0060:  6e71 9e03 0000 0000 eb2a 6bbb 9257 d613  nq.......*k..W..
        0x0070:  7463 4ec0 0000 0000 0000 090d            tcN.........
```

The server is listen to a list of sockets using select. I didn't implement the code but from what I see this is the branch that handles incoming traffic from clients. I will try to ass some print line in the code to see if it's arrive to this line of code.
Server code:

```
if (((cc_handler_das_msg_t *)buffer)->type == CC_HANDLER_DAS_MSG_TYPE_DATA) {
   *(uint32_t *)(&((cc_handler_das_msg_t *)buffer)->data+SW_FIFO_DATA_BUFF_SIZE*4)=i;
   write(message_net2iot_fifo_fd,&((cc_handler_das_msg_t *)buffer)->data,((cc_handler_das_msg_t *)buffer)->length/*valread*/);
   cc_handler_das_slave_data[i].ul_packets++;
  //printf("Master send message to iot\n");
} else if (((cc_handler_das_msg_t *)buffer)->type == CC_HANDLER_DAS_MSG_TYPE_KEEP_ALIVE) {
    cc_handler_das_slave_data[i].keep_alive++;
    ((cc_handler_das_msg_t *)message_buff)->type = CC_HANDLER_DAS_MSG_TYPE_KEEP_ALIVE;
    ((cc_handler_das_msg_t *)message_buff)->length = 0;
    send(sd , message_buff , sizeof(cc_handler_das_msg_t)-sizeof(uint8_t) , 0 );
    time(&cc_handler_das_slave_data[i].last_sent);
}
time(&cc_handler_das_slave_data[i].last_seen);
```

Comment: The message `MESSAGE1` is present in both logs starting at offset `0x0034`, ie: `004a 0d09 ..`

Comment: Please post your parsing code, so we can examine it

Comment: Hi. Maybe I confused you with the term "logs".
My server after received the packets suppose to pass it to some thread that parse it and store it in Database. You are right, both packets I captured has the same data, but only one of them (first one) is showing in the Database.

Comment: Also note that the client port number is present at offset `0x0014` and obviously is different in both cases. So it seems that you have logged a packet which includes header information as well as the body of the message.

Comment: Yes. I logged the complete packet using tcpdump. I copied the relevant server code in to my original post message

Comment: quamrana I understand you don't see any problem with the packets I sent? I should look in the code for problems?

Comment: So, you've used `tcpdump` to see the complete packet and the data is there. If your server code consists of: `if/elif` you might need an `else` to dump everything that isn't accepted to work out why not.

Comment: You are right. See my new post. Thank you and sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I'm feeling stupid. I found the problem. It's seems that my partner wrapped the data with some header and forgot to inform me. He added a "type" field to this header, the message was received by the master with illegal type!.

Sorry for troubling you.
quamrana you are right.